# Update @PrimaryKey value in Android Room

Tags: android, android-room

I want to update a bookmark, consisting of an url and a title, with the url as the primary key. Updating the title works flawlessly, but when I try to update the url, it doesn't work.

```
@Entity
public class Bookmark {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String url;

    private String title;

    ...
}
```

```
@Dao
public interface BookmarkDao {
    ...

    @Update
    int update(Bookmark bookmark);

    ...
}
```

```
bookmark.setTitle(title);
bookmark.setUrl(url);
bookmarkDao.update(bookmark);
```

The problem is, when overwriting the old url with setUrl, the @Update int update(Bookmark bookmark) method has no way of knowing which row to change.

My question is, is there some other possibility to update a primary key field by using @Update, or should I use @Query like this?

```
@Query("UPDATE Bookmark SET url = :url, title = :title WHERE url = :oldUrl")
int update(String oldUrl, String url, String title);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont make url your primary key. let it be handled by room itself just put PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) on key and then you dont have to worry about key at all

Comment: as Harkal said, you should not use URL as the primary key. The primary key is supposed to be immutable. If you still want to update, you have to use Query.